# Initialization failed exception when running on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a GAE application that works fine with Eclipse + Google plugin when executed within the localhost environment, however when I upload it to GAE server, (appspot) I get this error:

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Initialization failed.
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:228)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:194)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:134)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:447)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:454)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:461)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:703)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:338)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:330)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:458)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

I am not sure whether I have problems in my application as it works fine in localhost

Comment: We're going to need more info. Assuming that you developed your application incrementally, something must have tipped the application into the behaviour you're seeing. Can you back off to a stable place, and then post the change that causes the error you're seeing?

Comment: Actually I did not have a stable state in my AppEngine application, the first time I uploaded it, there where no errors and everything seemed OK until I accessed the URL

Comment: are all your entity classes implementing serializable?

Comment: @Devashish I am not using an Object-mapping, or any persistence manager. I store directly using the DatastoreService

Comment: @xybrek can you check if there is any error code shown in the logs? is the application taking more than to initialize during the startup?

Comment: Have the same issue. Are you on mac?

Comment: @tuxSlayer Same here on mac

Comment: This has only just started happening for me.  The main thing I can think of that I changed since it last worked was installing JDK8.  I am using Maven, and in my pom I force it to use JDK7, but it still happens.

Comment: @funkybro actually this question is very old, I am using GAE maven plugin now, but if you want to answer this question, go ahead. Thanks

Comment: @xybrek I don't have the answer, was hoping someone else might.